# Simple javascript onClick for table data

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a table of images in rows of 10 and I'm trying show the id of each image when I click on it.  I've tried many, many different ways of this (code below) but no joy.  Hopefully someone can set me straight.  No point in any jquery or other clever stuff though - I don't understand it yet.  Just some simple pointers would help a lot.

```
document.writeln('<table border = 1 >');

for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
    if (j % 10 == 0 && j !== 0){
        document.writeln('</tr><tr>');
    }

    document.writeln('<td ><img id = "' + myArray[j].id + '" src="' + myArray[j].src + '" onclick = selectImage() /></td>');
}

document.writeln('</tr></table>');

function selectImage() {
    alert(document.getElementById(id));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't "selectImage()" be wrapped in double-quotes?

Comment: Probably.  I tried that (and countless other ways) too but equally unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when making a call to selectImage, try passing the current image element by using the 'this' keyword i.e selectImage(this)

and then in the script, you can receive the passed object and retrieve the id attribute from there.

```
function selectImage(obj)
{
alert(obj.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it almost worked.  I now get a [object HTMLImageElement] in the alert window.  Must be close.  When you say (obj) and (obj.id) I just used x.  Forgive my ignorance but is that the problem maybe - what is obj?

Comment: No worries! 'obj' is the just a reference of the object passed into the function. You can name it whatever you want. In this case, 'obj' contains a reference to the image element.  Once we receive the image element, I am trying to pull the id attribute. Alternatively, you can directly pass the id into the function by modifying the function call to selectImage(this.id) in which case, you simply need to alert(obj) like this:     function selectImage(obj)
{
alert(obj);
}

Comment: You're a legend!  I used selectCard(this) and then function selectCard(x) {
    alert(x.id);
}

Comment: More help!  I think that's just referencing the table cell not the image id.  ie if I could shuffle them around it might still give the same output even though the image is in another cell.  Not sure how to tell just yet?  Don't s'pose you have any thoughts?  Cheers.

Comment: are you sure you are calling the function from the image element? From what you are saying, I think you may have added the function call on the table element?

Comment: Yep, all good.  Now fixed thanks.  Sometimes I just keep looking at the same error and not seeing it for what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need add a parameter to `selectImage` method, so we can send some information to those method. As you can see on my snippet:

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    id: "id01", 
    src: "src01.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "id02", 
    src: "src02.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "id03", 
    src: "src03.jpg"
  },
];

document.writeln('<table border = 1 >');

for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
    if (j % 10 == 0 && j !== 0){
        document.writeln('</tr><tr>');
    }

    document.writeln('<td ><img id = "' + myArray[j].id + '" src="' + myArray[j].src + '" onclick = selectImage(this) /></td>');
}

document.writeln('</tr></table>');

function selectImage(a) {
    console.log(a.getAttribute('src'));
    console.log(a.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that also.  I tried it and now get a ReferenceError: a is not defined
console.log(a.getAttribute('src'));

Comment: have you passing the argument at `onclick` event using `this`? like : `onclick = selectImage(this)`

Comment: Tried again with the (a) in the function arg and now I get no error but also nothing else.  Anyway the assignment requires nothing outside the material covered to date so I can't use (this) and I can't use (console.log).  Must be a simple answer but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I am feel confuse with your comment above. I think, I've give you simple answer.. *Have you try to run my snippet using `RUN CODE SNIPPET` button?* So, What do you mean about *assignment requires nothing outside the material covered to date so I can't use (this) and I can't use (console.log). Must be a simple answer but I'm just not seeing it.*

Comment: Yes I tried your snippet and it works very well.  I have 100's of images so I can't manually write them all in so I generate the table from the array.  We're only just starting the course and I haven't come across the console.log yet and we're specifically requested not to use anything beyond what has been covered in the course.  I used the (this) from another answer and it worked but I'm pretty sure I'll get marked down for it because we haven't covered that yet either.